# htaccess redirect for https, www and com to co.uk

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to solve this issue for hours now to no avail. To get to the point, I have identical domains with different TLDs, .com and .co.uk. Here's my htaccess file at the moment:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# com to co.uk redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've been trying to test the config here: http://htaccess.mwl.be/ but I'm getting some strange results, like the .com domain being appended to the .co.uk one.

It also seems like some rules work while others don't. The aim is all variations of example.com redirected to https://www.example.co.uk eg:

- www.example.com
- http://www.example.com
- https://example.com

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong with this? I'm not very experienced with htaccess redirects so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

The rule above will redirect :

- http://www.example.com

to

- https://www.example.co.uk

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that it doesn't seem to redirect: example.com to https://www.example.co.uk

Comment: Please clear your browser's cache or try a diffrent web browser to test this.